# DataAdapter.fill null value return error

Tags: c#, sql, database, dataadapter

I have a small sql statement that checks to see if there are any records that match error criteria so I can send out an alert. However most of the time there should not be any records that match the criteria. My issue is that when I run my program gets to the 'dataAdapt.fill(returnTable)' step, it throws an exception because the value is null. How can I avoid this? If the value is null I just want it to continue to where I can close out the program, not throw an exception.

```
try
{
    //open connection
    netezzaConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
    netezzaConn.Open();
    //execute sql statement
    OleDbCommand exe = new OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, netezzaConn);
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(exe);
    dataAdapt.Fill(returnTable);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}

if (returnTable.Rows.Count >= 1)
{
    recordCount = returnTable.Rows.Count;
    sendEmail.sendnotificationEmail(recordCount);
}
```

Comment: I don't see your actual command. exe has no query assigned to it.

Comment: Make sure returnTable isn't null before you try to fill it.

Comment: It's defined above I didn't include for security purposes, it's just a select statement.

Comment: Did you define your returnTable as dataset?
DataSet returnTable = new DataSet();

Comment: Oh wow that worked LarsTech! Thanks! Can you give any explanation as to why that made the difference?

Comment: I guess he could, but I may do it as well. The dataadapter trys to fill the dataset with the response of the sql query. But if the dataset is just declared, but not instanced, you can't access it, because actually you said your program that your variable "returnTable" is from the type of dataset, but it's no object placed in the variable. So at the end, you adapter can't access the dataset object to write to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the returnTable variable:

```
DataTable returnTable = new DataTable();
```

Without the "new", returnTable is a null object, and the DataAdapter will burp when it tries to use it.